# Clipping the current context so that it's masked by a path

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Given a path which is drawn to the context and then converted to a CGImageRef, how would I clip the context (which has a supplied foreground image drawn) to it so that the said context is masked by the CGImage (that previously was a path)?

The code in question below should better illustrate my point if it's not totally clear. Note that all of this is called in a UIView's drawRect: method and that the scaledImageRectangle(UIImage *image, CGRect rect) function merely returns a rectangle.

```
    // Close the path
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    // Mask the image
    CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    [foregroundImage drawInRect:scaledImageRectangle(foregroundImage, rect)];
    CGContextClipToMask(context, scaledImageRectangle(foregroundImage, rect), mask);

    // Finally draw the masked image
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
    [maskedImage drawInRect:scaledImageRectangle(foregroundImage, rect)];
```

For example, here is an image with the black stroke representing the path
[image: Before mask]

And here is what the image would look like when masked
[image: After mask]

Comment: Please take a step back and explain the end result that you're trying to achieve. The way you're doing this is weird. Normally, to clip to a path, you should just call `CGContextClip(path)` or `-[UIBezierPath addClip:]` -- you don't need to turn the path into an image.

Comment: Also, is `context` the current context from `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, or is it a separate context that you created?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that right now. Would it accomplish the same thing as masking an image?

Comment: It's the context returned by UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), but I have a feeling I should create a separate context for the path (if I end up going along this route at all).

Comment: Yes, clipping and masking can do similar things. A picture of what you're trying to do would help immensely. I suspect you're making it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I just did. Hopefully the pictures don't look too bad!

Answer (score 8):

I might be inclined to build a path as touches come in (I use `UIBezierPath`), and then your custom view can use that path for both clipping the image, as well as for stroking the path around that clipped image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    if (self.isClipped) {
        CGContextAddPath(context, [self.path CGPath]);
        CGContextClip(context);
    }

    [self.image drawInRect:self.bounds];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    self.path.lineWidth = 4.0;
    [self.path stroke];
}
```

[image: unclipped] [image: clipped]

If you want to draw the path as touches come in, I personally would render that via a separate `CAShapeLayer` (to avoid the unnecessary redrawing of the image).